# Too Many Dependency Inject

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I currently have a class with around 40 dependency injection. It is a hard to maintain and unit test. I am not sure a good way around.

The code is done for any type of application process that is needed to process (New License, License Renewal, Student Registration, ...), there are around 80 different types applications and what sections are associated with each application type is determined by a database table.

I have a class with all of the possible properties, there are a several more than listed but you should get the idea. Each the properties have their own set of properties that are basic data types or object pointing to other classes.

```
class Application
{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accounting")]
        public Accounting Accounting { get; set; }
   
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "application")]
        public Application Application { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "applicationType")]
        public ApplicationType ApplicationType { get; set; }
   
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "document")]
        public List<Attachment> Document { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "employment")]
        public List<Employment> Employment { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enrollment")]
        public Enrollment Enrollment { get; set; }
       
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "individualAddressContact")]
        public IndividualAddressContact IndividualAddressContact { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "instructors")]
        public List<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "license")]
        public License License { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "licenseRenewal")]
        public LicenseRenewal LicenseRenewal { get; set; }
   
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MilitaryService")]
        public List<MilitaryService> MilitaryService { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paymentDetail")]
        public PaymentDetail PaymentDetail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "photo")]
        public List<Attachment> Photo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "portal")]
        public Portal Portal { get; set; }
   
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "section")]
        public List<Section> Section { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "testingCalendar")]
        public TestingCalendar TestingCalendar { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "testingScore")]
        public List<TestingScore> TestingScore { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "USCitizen")]
        public USCitizen USCitizen { get; set; }
}
```

So this class is sent/received to an Angular 10 front end using Web API's.

When an application is requested the sections and the different properties are initiated and if the application has be started the progress will be reloaded. So it is possible some of properties will be pulled from the database and sent to the Angular app.

So I have something such as

```
Load(applicationTypeId, applicationId)
{
  Get the sections for the application type
  For each section in the sections
     switch sectionid
        case Documents
           Load all of the documents required for the application type and get any documents uploaded
        case Accounting
           Load the payment details, if no payment made calculate the payment
        case IndividualAddressContact
           Load the person name/address/contact and set a few defaults if the person hasn't started.
        .....
  next
}

Save()
{
     Save the application
     switch current section
        case Documents
           Save all of the documents for the application
        case Accounting
           Save the payment details for the application
        case IndividualAddressContact
           Save the person name/address/contact for the application
        .....       
     get the next section
     Update the application current section
}
```

I have put all of the items in the switch into their own classes but in the end I still have 1 point for serialization/deserialization and still end up with to many dependencies injected. Creating a unit test with over 40 dependencies seems hard to maintain and given I won't know which properties will/won't used until an application is requested and loaded from database. I am unsure how to get around the switch, without at some point and time having to have all of the dependencies injected into 1 class.

I would appreciate some ideas of how to get around this.

Comment: You need to have separate controller and/or action for each of the application type. Have separate models for each of them too... then add only needed dependencies to the specific controllers. And call appropriate API from the angular..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya wrong, multiple APi endpoints are a recipe for a super chatty and slow SPA.

Comment: The top level endpoint needs to be a broker for other services, each with their own dependencies, loaded on demand from an `IServiceProvider`. Consider the design of MVC, it doesn't load all the dependencies of every single end point for every request. You need to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using convention over configuration principle, with the Service Locator.

Declare something like `IApplicationHandler` interface in your program, e.g.

```
public interface IApplicationQueryHandler 
{
   Application Populate(Application application);
}

public interface IApplicationSaveHandler 
{
   Bool Save(Application application);
}
```

Then, write pieces of your code, with dependencies and such, e.g.

```
public class AccountingApplicationQueryHandler : IApplicationQueryHandler
{
   public Application Populate(Application application) {
     //// Load the payment details, if no payment made calculate the payment
    return application;
   }
}

public class AccountingApplicationSaveHandler : IApplicationSaveHandler
{
   public Bool Save(Application application) {
     //// Save the payment details for the application
    return true; // this just flags for validation
   }
}

// repeat for all other properties
```

Then in your controller, do something like

```
public class ApplicationController: Controller
{
   public readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   
   public ApplicationController(IServiceProvider sp) {
     _serviceProvider = sp;
   }

  public Application Load(string applicationTypeId, string applicationId)
  {
     var application = new Application(); // or get from db or whatever
     var queryHandlers = _serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IApplicationQueryHandler));

     foreach(var handler in queryHandlers) {
       application = handler.Populate(application);
     }
     
     return application;
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public bool Save(Application application) 
  {
    var result = true;
    var saveHandlers = _serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IApplicationSaveHandler));

     foreach(var handler in queryHandlers) {
       result = handler. Save(application);
     }
     
    return result;
  }
}
```

You would need to register your handlers, which you can do e.g. like so:

```
var queryHandlers = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IApplicationQueryHandler)).GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y == typeof(IApplicationQueryHandler)));

foreach(queryHandler in queryHandlers) {
  services.AddTransient(typeof(IApplicationQueryHandler), queryHandler);
}
// repeat the same for IApplicationSaveHandler
```

Now finally, you can write unit tests for part of the code like so

```
    [TestClass]
    public class AccountingApplicationQueryHandlerTests 
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestPopulate()
        {
            // arrange
            var application = new Application();
            var handler = new AccountingApplicationQueryHandler(); // inject mocks here

            // act
            var result = handler.Populate(application);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(result. PaymentDetail, "whatever");
        }
    }
```

And you can test that your controller calls the right things by mocking `IServiceProvider` and injecting that with a couple of dummy handlers to confirm they are called correctly.

Answer (score 2):

"I currently have a class with around 40 dependency injection..." - Oh my gosh!

"It is a hard to maintain and unit test..." - I don't doubt that in the least!

SUGGESTED REFACTORING:

1. Create a class that manages "Applications" (e.g. "ApplicationManager").
2. Create an abstract class "Application".

   One advantage of "abstract class" over "interface" here that you can put "common code" in the abstract base class.
3. Create a concrete subclass for each "Application" : `public class NewLicense : Application`, `public class LicenseRenewal : Application`, etc. etc.

... AND ...

4. Use DI *primarily* for those "services" that each *concrete class* needs.

   I'll bet the constructors for your individual concrete classes will only need to inject three or four services ... instead of 40.  Who knows - maybe your base class won't need any DI at all.

This is actually a design we're actually using in one of our production systems.  It's simple; it's robust; it's flexible.  It's working well for us :)

Comment: Concrete classes won't work, I prefer my method. I have added most of the application process without adding a line code. I just tell the system which components to use.
I have been trying to refactor some more but most the classes being passed in are super classes that each have 5-10 dependencies in them.

Answer (score 1):

Following zaitsman's answer you also could create `AggregatedApplicationQueryHandler` and `AggregatedApplicationSaveHandler` and pass collection of concrete implementation of `IApplicationQueryHandler` and `IApplicationSaveHandler` to its constructor.

Then you don't need `foreach` loop inside controller(you loop over handlers inside aggregated handler) and always have only one handler passed to controller. Passing its by constructor parameter shouldn't be so much painful.

You also could create facade over some small services and aggregate theirs functions into one bigger facade service.